# How to name the second element?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

As a programmer with OCD (Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder), I wonder usually how people name the second element (variable, file name, etc.) in the programmer's world?

For example, I create a file with the name `file`. I do NOT expect there is another one in this series.

However, one day I got a second one. What usually do you name it?
For example, it can be `file1`, or `file2`, or `file0`, or `file_b`, or `fileB`, or `file_`, or `file (1)` ...

There could be a lot. Which one is better (for some reasons)?

I am mostly concerned about `file2` VS `file1`, as element starts from `0` in the computer science world, however the real world starts from `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how exactly it should read, I think most people will do `file_001`or `file_002` but I've seen it on professionally-written code many different ways, though all numbering systems use numbers and not letters.

Also, always name your files with leading leading zeros so that the files don't get out of order: `file11` would come before `file2` in this case, so do something like `file011` and `file002`.

It's usually not a big deal, but open source projects may specify a way to name files in the readme.  If file naming is important to you, it never hurts to explain how you name your files in your project readme.

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, it's better to refactor instead of patching up the current "code": rename the first `file` as well (to `file1`, `file_01`, `file_a` or whatever), unless that would cause too much trouble (but even in that case, it would make sense to consider using a "view": leave the current `file` but add a `file_01` hardlink/softlink to it - or probably better, a softlink from `file` to `file_01`).

For filenames in particular leaving`file` as is will be annoying because it will usually get placed after the numbered files in directory listings.

---

And in the last paragraph, I imagine you meant `file0` VS `file1`...?
If so, I'd say to go with 1, it's much more common in my experience.

And it's not true that *element starts from 0 in the computer science world*, that's indeed what most programming languages and maybe about all low-level stuff do, but it's not a must, and by personal experience I guarantee you that when you can without too much risk starting with 1 in many cases helps readibility a lot, and this base-0 thing is one of the many mantras that should be let go in software development.

But in any case for naming files and stuff in general (as opposed to array-indexing) it's more common to start from 1 (in my experience).